# Unable to get Clien'ts ip adress in Express App

Tags: node.js, express, ip

I'm trying to get the IP adress of a client who made a request to my express app, I was trying this:

```
var ip = req.header('x-forwarded-for') || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

and also :

```
 app.set('trust proxy', true);
    var ip=req.ip
```

but all I got was 127.0.0.1, is there a way to get the real IP address?

Comment: Is there any reverse proxy in front of your node server? Something like nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

1) `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']`

2) `req.connection.remoteAddress`

3) `req.socket.remoteAddress`

4) `req.connection.socket.remoteAddress`

If still not working, you may try to use [request-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip) npm package which make multiple checks. [This is a code example](https://github.com/pbojinov/request-ip/blob/master/examples/connect-middleware-simple.js) of how to use it.

Comment: none of it works, including the request-IP package which I tried earlier, I still get that default IP address.